# Visualizing netCDF file with unknown projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, coordinate-system, netcdf

I'm having a tough time visualizing a netCDF file with poor metadata in ArcMap, which is probably not a surprise. I know the file to contain ozone concentrations over the United States. If I try to bring the layer into ArcMap using "Make NetCDF Raster Layer" I get the following:
[image: Something isn't lining up]

Clearly something isn't right, but it's *kind of* close. The US states layer is in straight WGS84. If it's helpful, the bottom left corner of the netCDF layer is at (0, 0) decimal degrees. If I open it up in [Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/download.html), it works fine without modification, which suggests to me that the file contains some kind of helpful information, somewhere: 
[image: It works!]

I've surmised that gdalwarp should be able to help, but I'm not sure how. If I run gdalinfo on the netCDF file, I get the following:

```
>> gdalinfo MAX8hr_4th.2050_T2_year

Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: MAX8hr_4th.2050_T2_year
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  NC_GLOBAL#CDATE=2013282
  NC_GLOBAL#CTIME=144932
  NC_GLOBAL#EXEC_ID=????????????????                                                                
  NC_GLOBAL#FILEDESC=Concentration file output Averaged over the synchronization time steps
  Timestamp represents beginning computed date/time 
  Layer mapping (CGRID to AGRID): Layer  1 to 1                                                                                                                                     
  NC_GLOBAL#FTYPE=1
  NC_GLOBAL#GDNAM=clim36
  NC_GLOBAL#GDTYP=2
  NC_GLOBAL#HISTORY=
  NC_GLOBAL#IOAPI_VERSION=$Id: @(#) ioapi library version 3.0 $                                     
  NC_GLOBAL#NCOLS=148
  NC_GLOBAL#NLAYS=4
  NC_GLOBAL#NROWS=122
  NC_GLOBAL#NTHIK=1
  NC_GLOBAL#NVARS=1
  NC_GLOBAL#P_ALP=33
  NC_GLOBAL#P_BET=45
  NC_GLOBAL#P_GAM=-97
  NC_GLOBAL#SDATE=2050001
  NC_GLOBAL#STIME=80000
  NC_GLOBAL#TSTEP=240000
  NC_GLOBAL#UPNAM=MAX8HRCELL
  NC_GLOBAL#VAR-LIST=O3
  NC_GLOBAL#VGLVLS={1,0,0,0,0}
  NC_GLOBAL#VGTOP=5000
  NC_GLOBAL#VGTYP=7
  NC_GLOBAL#WDATE=2013282
  NC_GLOBAL#WTIME=144932
  NC_GLOBAL#XCELL=36000
  NC_GLOBAL#XCENT=-97
  NC_GLOBAL#XORIG=-2736000
  NC_GLOBAL#YCELL=36000
  NC_GLOBAL#YCENT=40
  NC_GLOBAL#YORIG=-2448000
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"MAX8hr_4th.2050_T2_year":TFLAG
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[1x1x2] TFLAG (32-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=NETCDF:"MAX8hr_4th.2050_T2_year":O3
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[1x4x122x148] O3 (32-bit floating-point)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

which appears to contain some spatial information (NC_GLOBAL#XCENT, NC_GLOBAL#XORIG, etc.), but I'm unsure how to employ it.

Here's the output from a call to `ncdump -h ozone.nc` (filename shortened for brevity).

```
dimensions:
        TSTEP = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
        DATE-TIME = 2 ;
        LAY = 4 ;
        VAR = 1 ;
        ROW = 122 ;
        COL = 148 ;
variables:
        int TFLAG(TSTEP, VAR, DATE-TIME) ;
                TFLAG:units = "<YYYYDDD,HHMMSS>" ;
                TFLAG:long_name = "TFLAG           " ;
                TFLAG:var_desc = "Timestep-valid flags:  (1) YYYYDDD or (2) HHMMSS                                " ;
        float O3(TSTEP, LAY, ROW, COL) ;
                O3:long_name = "O3              " ;
                O3:units = "ppbV            " ;
                O3:var_desc = "Linear combination of \"O3\"                                                      " ;

// global attributes:
                :IOAPI_VERSION = "$Id: @(#) ioapi library version 3.0 $                                           " ;
                :EXEC_ID = "????????????????                                                                " ;
                :FTYPE = 1 ;
                :CDATE = 2013282 ;
                :CTIME = 144749 ;
                :WDATE = 2013282 ;
                :WTIME = 144749 ;
                :SDATE = 2010001 ;
                :STIME = 80000 ;
                :TSTEP = 240000 ;
                :NTHIK = 1 ;
                :NCOLS = 148 ;
                :NROWS = 122 ;
                :NLAYS = 4 ;
                :NVARS = 1 ;
                :GDTYP = 2 ;
                :P_ALP = 33. ;
                :P_BET = 45. ;
                :P_GAM = -97. ;
                :XCENT = -97. ;
                :YCENT = 40. ;
                :XORIG = -2736000. ;
                :YORIG = -2448000. ;
                :XCELL = 36000. ;
                :YCELL = 36000. ;
                :VGTYP = 7 ;
                :VGTOP = 5000.f ;
                :VGLVLS = 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f ;
                :GDNAM = "clim36          " ;
                :UPNAM = "MAX8HRCELL      " ;
                :VAR-LIST = "O3              " ;
                :FILEDESC = "Concentration file output                                                       Averaged over the synchronization time steps                                    Timestamp represents beginning computed date/time                               Layer mapping (CGRID to AGRID):                                                 Layer  1 to  1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  " ;
                :HISTORY = "" ;
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on some additional information synthesized from the data's source and the metadata, I gathered that the data are already in a Lambert Conformal projection but that ArcMap isn't able to extract that info from the metadata. My approach has been to use `gdal_translate` to properly embed the projection information in the netCDF file. The following call gets *very* close, but is not quite there:

```
gdal_translate -of netCDF -a_ullr -2736000 2448000 2736000 -2448000 -a_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_1=33 +lat_2=45 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-97 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=sphere +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs" NETCDF:"MAX8hr_4th.2050_T2_year":O3 out.nc
```

This gives me the following in Arc:

[image: It works!]

It seems like the data need to be shifted west and south slightly, but I'm not sure how to do that precisely given that I've used the best information I can get from the metadata already. One idea is that the assumed radius of the Earth needs to be changed (I believe the data are based on a spherical assumption from investigation within Panoply), but changing the proj4 definition to `+ellps=sphere` doesn't change the assumed spheroid, as shown in the call to `gdalinfo` which now returns:

```
Warning 1: dimension #1 (LAY) is not a Time  dimension.
Warning 1: dimension #0 (TSTEP) is not a Time  dimension.
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: ozone6.nc
Size is 148, 122
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",33],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",40],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-97],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (-2736000.000000000000000,2447999.999999999500000)
Pixel Size = (36972.972972972981000,-40131.147540983598000)
Metadata:
  lambert_conformal_conic#false_easting=0
  lambert_conformal_conic#false_northing=0
  lambert_conformal_conic#GeoTransform=-2736000 36972.97297297297 0 2448000 0 -40131.14754098361
  lambert_conformal_conic#grid_mapping_name=lambert_conformal_conic
  lambert_conformal_conic#inverse_flattening=298.257222101
  lambert_conformal_conic#latitude_of_projection_origin=40
  lambert_conformal_conic#longitude_of_central_meridian=-97
  lambert_conformal_conic#longitude_of_prime_meridian=0
  lambert_conformal_conic#semi_major_axis=6378137
  lambert_conformal_conic#spatial_ref=PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",33],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",40],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-97],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
  lambert_conformal_conic#standard_parallel={33,45}
  NC_GLOBAL#CDATE=2013282
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.5
  NC_GLOBAL#CTIME=144749
  NC_GLOBAL#EXEC_ID=????????????????                                                                
  NC_GLOBAL#FILEDESC=Concentration file output                                                       Averaged over the synchronization time steps                                    Timestamp represents beginning computed date/time                               Layer mapping (CGRID to AGRID):                                                 Layer  1 to  1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  NC_GLOBAL#FTYPE=1
  NC_GLOBAL#GDAL=GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16
  NC_GLOBAL#GDNAM=clim36
  NC_GLOBAL#GDTYP=2
  NC_GLOBAL#history=Tue May 03 12:44:02 2016: GDAL CreateCopy( ozone6.nc, ... )
  NC_GLOBAL#IOAPI_VERSION=$Id: @(#) ioapi library version 3.0 $                                     
  NC_GLOBAL#NCOLS=148
  NC_GLOBAL#NLAYS=4
  NC_GLOBAL#NROWS=122
  NC_GLOBAL#NTHIK=1
  NC_GLOBAL#NVARS=1
  NC_GLOBAL#P_ALP=33
  NC_GLOBAL#P_BET=45
  NC_GLOBAL#P_GAM=-97
  NC_GLOBAL#SDATE=2010001
  NC_GLOBAL#STIME=80000
  NC_GLOBAL#TSTEP=240000
  NC_GLOBAL#UPNAM=MAX8HRCELL
  NC_GLOBAL#VAR-LIST=O3
  NC_GLOBAL#VGLVLS={1,0,0,0,0}
  NC_GLOBAL#VGTOP=5000
  NC_GLOBAL#VGTYP=7
  NC_GLOBAL#WDATE=2013282
  NC_GLOBAL#WTIME=144749
  NC_GLOBAL#XCELL=36000
  NC_GLOBAL#XCENT=-97
  NC_GLOBAL#XORIG=-2736000
  NC_GLOBAL#YCELL=36000
  NC_GLOBAL#YCENT=40
  NC_GLOBAL#YORIG=-2448000
  NETCDF_DIM_EXTRA={TSTEP,LAY}
  NETCDF_DIM_LAY_DEF={4,5}
  NETCDF_DIM_LAY_VALUES={9.96921e+036,9.96921e+036,9.96921e+036,9.96921e+036}
  NETCDF_DIM_TSTEP_DEF={1,5}
  NETCDF_DIM_TSTEP_VALUES=9.96921e+036
  O3#_FillValue=9.96921e+036
  O3#grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
  O3#long_name=O3
  O3#units=ppbV
  O3#var_desc=Linear combination of O3
  x#long_name=x coordinate of projection
  x#standard_name=projection_x_coordinate
  x#units=m
  y#long_name=y coordinate of projection
  y#standard_name=projection_y_coordinate
  y#units=m
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-2736000.000, 2448000.000) (140d30'40.39"W, 55d50'15.32"N)
Lower Left  (-2736000.000,-2448000.000) (120d53'22.23"W, 15d10'27.73"N)
Upper Right ( 2736000.000, 2448000.000) ( 53d29'19.61"W, 55d50'15.32"N)
Lower Right ( 2736000.000,-2448000.000) ( 73d 6'37.77"W, 15d10'27.73"N)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) ( 97d 0' 0.00"W, 40d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=148x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.969209968386869e+036
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=9.96921e+036
    grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
    long_name=O3
    NETCDF_DIM_LAY=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_DIM_TSTEP=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_VARNAME=O3
    units=ppbV
    var_desc=Linear combination of O3
Band 2 Block=148x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.969209968386869e+036
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=9.96921e+036
    grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
    long_name=O3
    NETCDF_DIM_LAY=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_DIM_TSTEP=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_VARNAME=O3
    units=ppbV
    var_desc=Linear combination of O3
Band 3 Block=148x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.969209968386869e+036
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=9.96921e+036
    grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
    long_name=O3
    NETCDF_DIM_LAY=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_DIM_TSTEP=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_VARNAME=O3
    units=ppbV
    var_desc=Linear combination of O3
Band 4 Block=148x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=9.969209968386869e+036
  Metadata:
    _FillValue=9.96921e+036
    grid_mapping=lambert_conformal_conic
    long_name=O3
    NETCDF_DIM_LAY=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_DIM_TSTEP=9.96921e+036
    NETCDF_VARNAME=O3
    units=ppbV
    var_desc=Linear combination of O3
```

Comment: Can you edit in the output of `ncdump -h dataset.nc`? Or post a link to the data?

Comment: Yes - just edited in the output from ncdump. I can also post the data if it would be helpful.

Comment: You should not use `+datum=NAD83` together with `+ellps=sphere`, NAD83 will override the sphere definition. Instead, use `+R=6370000`.

Answer (score 1):

The metadata in the CDL dump indicate the data is using the M3IOConvention, from the Models-3/EDSS API, which I assume you already knew based on your comments about interpreting the metadata. Checking the netCDF-Java library (used by Panoply) source code for handling that convention, I see that the Earth radius is hard-coded as 6370.0 km. Whether using that value is enough to shift the data position as you desire, I can't say, but it's something else to check.

Comment: Follow-up seven months later... I see from a patch posted to the Unidata/thredds repo on Github recently that there may have also been a problem with the netCDF-Java library  such that the M3IOConvention grid -- "Without this fix, visualization softwares IDV and Panoply will display rasters spatially shifted half a grid cell to the southwest." See [link](https://github.com/Unidata/thredds/pull/757)